# What is $\tan(\operatorname{arcsec} (x))$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What is $\def\arcsec{\operatorname{arcsec}}\tan(\arcsec(x))$ simplified and why?

More specifically, I followed this reasoning, but apparently it is wrong:

$\tan(\arcsec(x))=\sqrt{\sec^2(\arcsec(x))-1}=\sqrt{x^2-1}$

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Apparently the answer is: $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ for $x\ge1$ and $-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ for $x\le1$ Why is this the right answer?

Comment: it is $$\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} x$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition we have:
$$
y=\mbox{arcsec}x \iff \sec y=x \Rightarrow \cos y=\frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow \sin y=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \tan y = \frac{\sin y}{\cos y}=x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{x}{|x|}\sqrt{x^2-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks! And what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: You have forgot the possible two signs of the square root:  $\tan \alpha=\pm \sqrt{\sec^2 \alpha-1}$, where the sign depend on the position of $\alpha$

Comment: But isn't always $sin(\alpha)=\sqrt{1-cos^2(\alpha)}$ without $\pm$?

Comment: What do you mean by the position of $\alpha$?

Comment: Hint: $\sin \alpha=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \alpha}$ for $0\le\alpha \le \pi$, but change sign for $\pi<\alpha\le 2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating. Let $\def\arcsec{\operatorname{arcsec}}f(x)=\tan(\arcsec x)$. Then
$$
f'(x)=\sec^2(\arcsec x)\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$
(assuming $\arcsec$ is as the inverse of the secant over the set $[0,\pi/2)\cup(\pi/2,\pi]$), so
$$
f'(x)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$
Therefore, for $x>1$,
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}+c_+
$$
and, since $f(1)=\tan0=0$, we have $c_+=0$. For $x<-1$,
$$
f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2-1}+c_-
$$
and, since $f(-1)=\tan\pi=0$, we have again $c_-=0$. Thus
$$
\tan(\arcsec x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2-1}
$$